# Installing python packages on the workers in Databricks restarts the interpreter

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, azure-databricks, mlflow

I have a machine learning job in prod that keeps failing because of the reason below:

```
InvalidConfigurationError: You haven't configured the CLI yet! Please configure by entering `/databricks/python_shell/scripts/PythonShell.py configure`
```

To address it, I then installed the packages on the workers by doing:

```
%pip install
```

as shown in https://community.databricks.com/s/feed/0D53f00001HKIENCA5, instead of

```
%sh

pip install
```

The new problem that I now have is that '%pip' restarts the python interpreter and I do not want that because I lose any python computing done before the command.

Question: How do I install a package on the workers without restarting the python interpreter?

Comment: You can run %pip as the first cell.  
Also, you can install the packages needed on the cluster (preferably job cluster)